# Put DIV in front of FLASH (IE, Safari; wmode not applicable)

Tags: css, xhtml

Simple z-index works for Chrome, Firefox and Opera browser. It doesn't work in IE (11) and Safari, but I'm more concern about Internet Explorer.

I can't change wmode since it's 3rd party ad network. Any suggestions?

```
<div class="flash">any generic ad network banner js code</div>
<div class="foo">foo</div>
```

Comment: How could we help without any code?

Comment: @HashemQolami, think of any banner like adsense and try to put DIV in front of it.. what do you need a code for?

Comment: @HashemQolami, I have added a simple code for demonstration. I can't show you full JS code for banner. First of all, I could hardly find every js dependencies, second - they might change it in any time or we could switch media agency ... I need something generic